# Тонкости работы с реакт декоратором

Tags: reactjs, декоратор

Сделал, казалось бы, удобный декоратор для контроля за hover событиями. Но оказалось, что он работает своенравно, для экземпляров разных классов он не ленится создавать новые классы декораторов, однако для нескольких экземпляров одного класса он также создает всего один экземпляр декоратора и оборачивает в него все компоненты.

код декоратора:

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {RegisterHoverAC, ToggleHoverAC} from "../redux/ux/hoverReducer";

const withHover = WrappedComponent => {

    const key1 = Math.random().toString(36).substring(8)
    const key2 = Math.random().toString(36).substring(8)
    const randomKey = "hover_" + key1 + "_" + key2

    const mapStateToProps = (state) =>
    {
        const hover = state.ux.hover.hovers.find((hover) => {return hover.key === randomKey})
        return { isHover: hover ? hover.isHover : false }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            /** Toggle hover status */
            toggleHover: (isHover) => {
                dispatch(ToggleHoverAC(isHover, randomKey))
            },

            registerHover: () => {
                dispatch(RegisterHoverAC(randomKey))
            }
        }
    }

    class Decorator extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.toggleHoverHandler = this.toggleHoverHandler.bind(this)
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            console.log(randomKey)
            this.props.registerHover(randomKey)
        }

        toggleHoverHandler (status) {
            this.props.toggleHover(status)
        }

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} isHover={this.props.isHover} toggleHover={this.toggleHoverHandler} />
        }
    }

    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Decorator)
}
export default withHover
```

Иными словами, декоратор создается не для отдельного экземпляра, а для самого класса. И к каждому новому экземпляру подцепляет инстанс однажды созданного класса декоратора.

Вопрос, собственно в том как бы это поправить.Чтобы он честно создавал новые классы декораторов для каждого отдельного экземпляра.

Answer (score 0):

Переделал:

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {RegisterHoverAC, ToggleHoverAC} from "../redux/ux/hoverReducer";

export const generateRandomKey = () => {
    const key1 = Math.random().toString(36).substring(8)
    const key2 = Math.random().toString(36).substring(8)
    return "hover_" + key1 + "_" + key2
}

export const withHover = WrappedComponent => {

    const mapStateToProps = (state) =>
    {
        return { hovers:state.ux.hover.hovers }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            /** Toggle hover status */
            toggleHover: (isHover, randomKey) => {
                dispatch(ToggleHoverAC(isHover, randomKey))
            },

            registerHover: (randomKey) => {
                dispatch(RegisterHoverAC(randomKey))
            }
        }
    }

    class Decorator extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.toggleHoverHandler = this.toggleHoverHandler.bind(this)
            this.randomKey = generateRandomKey()
            console.log('constructor:' + this.randomKey)

        }

        componentDidMount() {
            console.log ('register hover')
            this.props.registerHover(this.randomKey)
        }

        toggleHoverHandler (status) {
            console.log(this.randomKey)
            this.props.toggleHover(status, this.randomKey)
        }

        render() {

            const hover = this.props.hovers.find((hover) => {return hover.key === this.randomKey})
            const isHover =  hover ? hover.isHover : false

            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} isHover={isHover} toggleHover={this.toggleHoverHandler} />
        }
    }

    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Decorator)
}
export default withHover
```